# When I use transform:rotate on a fixed div it leaves an empty space at the top of the page?

Tags: css, rotation, transform

I have a fixed div on with a height of 100% on the left side of my webpage. When I use `transform:rotate(6deg);` it leaves an empty space at the top of the page. I have tried to add height to it, but it just makes it worse. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks! (:

Answer (score 0):

Is it triangular space left?
After rotating div with 100% height it probably also resizes width of page?
Problem is probably in point of rotation.

Please give more details - somehow this div need to be cut (shifted).